# Segmentation fault in my C application

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, fgets, scanf

I'm new to using `fgets` so I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I need to make a table of floats but I keep seg faulting during the standard input. I took out all the "unnecessary" code for readability so yes I do use all the arguments in the parameters. It seg faults even when I enter one number.

```
typedef struct row
{
    int column;
    float value[20];
}ROW;

//in main ROW table[100];

void makeTable2(ROW* table, int* row, int* column)
{
    int counter = 0, counter2;
    int y = 0;

    char str[256], again;

    printf("Enter in the table: ");

    do{

        fgets(str, 256, stdin);

        while(sscanf(str, "%f", &table[*row].value[y]))
            y++;

        (*row)++;

        printf("Add another row? (y or n)? ");
        scanf("%c", &again);

    }while(again == 'y' || again == 'Y');
}
```

Comment: Where do you allocate memory for ROW ? Some code please.

Comment: //in main ROW table[100];

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in line

```
   while(sscanf(str, "%f", &table[*row].value[y]))
```

you're reading your first number every time, NOT NEXT, only first, and get buffer overflow when y exceeds value 20.
Try scanf() every value separately.

Comment: so sscanf doesn't parse fgets?

Comment: it parses, but not as reading from buffer, readden values not dissapearing

Comment: add printf("%d : %f\r\n", y, table[*row].value[y]); in while loop body and see what you're reading only first value.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(sscanf(str, "%f", &table[*row].value[y]))
     y++;
```

That's an infinite loop. You always read from the first float value present in the str buffer and eventually y become more than 19 and there is segmentation fault.